# Spider gets different results on ubuntu and windows

Tags: python, ubuntu

I get different results depending on whether my Spider is run from ubuntu or run from Windows. The code is same.
The ubuntu is run on my cloud server. It can get the number of search results, but the two get different results.
Also, when it runs on ubuntu, it may fail. Someone told me it may be caused by a cookie, but I don't understand why.
This is my code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json
import re

#
class baidu(object):
    def __init__(self,keyword):
        self.keyword = keyword


    #get result number  
    def GetNumber(self):
        base_url = 'https://www.baidu.com/s?'
        params  = { 'wd':self.keyword,
                   'ie': 'UTF-8',
                }
        headers =  {
                'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.117 Safari/537.36',
                'Host': 'www.baidu.com',
                'is_referer': 'https://www.baidu.com/',
                'Referer': 'https://www.baidu.com/',
                'is_xhr': '1',
                'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
                'Sec-Fetch-Site': 'same-origin',
                'Connection': 'keep-alive',
                'Sec-Fetch-Mode': 'cors',
                'Cookie': ''
        }


        #,cookies=cookieDict
        content  = requests.get(base_url,params=params,headers=headers)
        #print(content.url)
        content.encoding = 'uft-8'
        try:
            span_content = BeautifulSoup(content.text,'html.parser').find(class_="nums_text").get_text()
        except Exception as e:
            print('fail')
            print(e)
            return 0
        nums = re.findall('\d+',span_content)
        num = int(''.join(nums))
        return num

if __name__ == '__main__':
    keyword = '酒精、小苏打'
    p = baidu(keyword=keyword).GetNumber()
    print(p)
```

windows:

收起工具时间不限所有网页和文件站点内检索搜索工具百度为您找到相关结果约10,900,000个

ubuntu:

收起工具时间不限所有网页和文件站点内检索搜索工具百度为您找到相关结果约3,860个

Comment: grammar, text formatting

Comment: Welcome to SO. Images are pure black. Anyway, all code, output, data, & error messages must be entered as plain text (and formatted as code or quote (for error messages & output). It's too difficult to read text in images, especially from mobile devices (and takes a lot of bandwidth to view). Additionally, code, data, & error messages need to be copy-pastable into user's editors & search engines, for volunteers to help efficiently, as well as to avoid introducing their own typos. Please `edit` to add the your results as text, and delete the image references. Review the Help pages for more info

Comment: Search engines do lots of things to try to customize the results. For example, they will look at your IP address and try to infer your location from that and then return results they think will be more relevant to your location. It's possible that something like that is happening. It's a little hard to know given that some relevant parts like the query string are in a language I don't know.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Maybe I can use the same IP and see if I can get the same result.